# Angular scope not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have controller like:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.daysPerMonth = new Date(year, month).getDate();
}]
);
```

And html:

```
<div ng-app>

  <h1>How many days has month?</h1>

  <input ng-model="month" type="text" placeholder="Set a month as number">

  <input ng-model="year" type="text" placeholder="Set a year as number">

  <p ng-if="year" ng-model="daysPerMonth">
    In {{ month }} of {{ year }}, we have {{ daysPerMonth }} days.
  </p>

</div>
```

Why it does not work?

https://jsfiddle.net/m7aLdwe1/

Comment: you didnt add your ctrl name in html

Comment: It only works without ng-controller if you use `angular-route` which resolves the controller depending on the route.

Comment: I add ng-controller and nth > https://jsfiddle.net/m7aLdwe1/3/

Answer (score 1):

try this.you forgot add ng-contoller and ng-app
i just correct your mistakes.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
 app.controller('ctrl',['$scope', function ($scope) {
      
      //change your logic to compute ... 
      
 }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <h1>How many days has month?</h1>
  
  <input ng-model="month" type="text" placeholder="Set a month as number">
  
  <input ng-model="year" type="text" placeholder="Set a year as number">
  
  <p ng-if="year" >
    In {{ month }} of {{ year }} ......
  </p>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Where you using $scope in html?